# How can I stop a video with Javascript in Youtube?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

**Situation:**
[here,](http://yvoschaap.com/videowall/?q=sunset%20beautiful) where I pressed some video.

**Problem:** I try to stop the video by Javascript in the console of Firebug:

```
player.stopVideo(playerid):Void   [1] [2]
```

**Question:** Why does not the command above work?

[1] [Source](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html) for the part "player.stopVideo():Void"

[2] I looked playerid with Firebug from the source.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your video is requesting w/ the JSAPI enabled, so you are very close! All you need is a valid reference to the embedded player. Inspecting your page revealed that you are using the HTML DOM element id of "playerid" to identify your player.

Example:

```
<embed id="playerid" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" name="playerid" style="" src="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayerbeta?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=normalplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

To obtain a reference to the player and then stop the video use the following code:

```
var myPlayer = document.getElementById('playerid');
myPlayer.stopVideo();
```

Comment: Sentence: "Your video is requesting w/ the JSAPI enabled, so you are very close!" So it does not work without the API enabled?

Comment: So I am only able to control things like on the site, if the developer has designed an API on it? I feel it weird because JS is run on the client. Why would it not be possible to control JS on any arbitrary site without JS API enabled?

Comment: YouTube specified that their player can not be controlled via JS unless the video is requested with the JSAPI enabled. To enable it, one just needs to request the YouTube video with the following GET line parameter: enablejsapi=1 



More information & examples: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

Answer (score 5):

The following works well, tested on wamp server. Just replace the 11-digit ID in the following line with that of the video you want to play.

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/***LpbzbyGjJGE***?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer
```

Good luck.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<a href="#" onclick="var myPlayer = document.getElementById('playerid'); myPlayer.pauseVideo();">Pause</a>
<a href="#" onclick="var myPlayer = document.getElementById('playerid'); myPlayer.playVideo();">Play</a>
<embed id="playerid" width="500px" height="400px" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" name="playerid" style="" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/LpbzbyGjJGE?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

So this is quickest way to do it!

Open Developer Options

Hover over YouTube play button.

Press Control/Command + Shift + C

Select the Button

Add id to it.

Go to console and run the following

var x = document.getElementById('id');
x.click();

That's it!