# Twitter Bootstrap modal and Youtube autoplay and stop when closed

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop a video with Javascript in Youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094397/how-can-i-stop-a-video-with-javascript-in-youtube)

I was wondering how I can use Twitter Bootstrap's modal feature to autoplay a Youtube video and when a user clicks the "close" button, it will stop the video from playing.

I have tried adding the following to my application.js file without prevail.

```
$('#my-video').on('hide', function () {
  player.stopVideo();
})
```

HTML view

```
<div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/30Pjl31cyDY?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any insights is much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931798/hide-show-in-javascript-stop-playing-youtube-iframe-video

Answer (score 0):

```
player.stopVideo();
```

will only work if `player` is a YT.player object that you have created via the Youtube API.  You can learn how to control the youtube player via javascript here:  https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference