# Stop Youtube Upon Clicking Close Button

Tags: jquery, html, youtube

```
<div id="popup-box1" class="popup-position">  
    <div id="popup-wrapper">

      <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="close" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box1');"><img src="images/icon_x.png"></a></p>

      <iframe width="640" height="360" class="yvideo"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lQhkpmEd3Fo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </div>
  </div>
```

I am trying to use jQuery to close as well as stop the YouTube video from playing. As it is now, I close the video popup, but the video / sound continues to play when the popup is closed. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this similar question/answer:

[Hide/show in JavaScript - stop playing YouTube iframe video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931798/hide-show-in-javascript-stop-playing-youtube-iframe-video)

looks like adding ?enablejsapi=1 to your video requests will allow you to post play/stop commands to the iframe