# Sencha Touch2 Stop YouTube video when I go to another page

Tags: youtube, sencha-touch-2

How can I stop or pause a YouTube Video from playing when I go to another page

In Sencha Touch2 Here is my code it seems like it should work but Video still plays.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.tablet.Home5', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'home5',

config: {
    scrollable: true,
    cls:'logo',

    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            id: 'videopanel',
            html:[
                '<div id="video1"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NSUucup09Hc?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>',
                '<img src="resources/images/thapelo3Fy.jpg" />'
            ].join("")
        }
    ]
},

hide: function(container, options){
    this.callParent(arguments);

    //workaround to stop the video (= reset the html)
    Ext.getCmp('videopanel').setHtml("");
    Ext.getCmp('videopanel').setHtml('<div id="video1"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NSUucup09Hc?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><img src="resources/images/thapelo3Fy.jpg" />');
}
});
```

Comment: You can control YouTube videos in iframes with the Javascript Player Api. [Check out this link](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/01/introducing-javascript-player-api-for.html)

Comment: My last post got voted down and deleted, but this new link should help and demonstrate the correct use of ExtgetCmp in Sencha Touch 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470957/ext-getcmp-not-working-on-hide-of-youtube-video-sencha-touch/11481878#11481878

Answer (score 0):

[How can I stop a video with Javascript in Youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094397/how-can-i-stop-a-video-with-javascript-in-youtube) is what you need to do. Would have typed it here, but on my mobile...