# can't stop deeply nested youtube video

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube

I can't seem to get a YouTube video to stop playing when a modal is closed. The video goes away but the audio continues playing.

I've tried the solutions in many other questions but nothing seems to work. I think it's probably because my video is deeply nested and I haven't been able to target it. And/or because the iframes have element IDs of the same names. (Don't get me started.)

Here's a simplified look at the DOM:

```
html
  head
  body
    <div id="popoverview">
      <div id="popoveritem">
        <iframe id="popoverframe">   <!-- this is our modal -->
          #document
            html
              head
              body
                <div id="popovercontainer">
                  <div id="popover_upc_video">
                    <div id="current_video">
                      <div id="player">
                        <iframe id="popoverframe">
                          #document  <!-- this is from youtube -->
                            html
                              head
                              body
                                <div id="player">
                                  <div id="playercontainer">
                                    <embed id="video-player-flash">  <!-- the video -->
```

Here's a bit from the javascript inserting the youtube video--including ?enablejsapi=1 --into the modal:

```
document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = '<iframe id="youtubevideo" width="620" height="376" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+youtube_id+'?enablejsapi=1?hl=en&rel=0&fs=1&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>Error?</iframe>';
```

Here's a bit from the function that closes the modal. Problem is that the audio keeps playing. The error message is Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'stopVideo'.

```
var myPlayer = $('#player > #video-player-flash');
myPlayer.stopVideo();
```

I've tried quite a few methods of targeting but nothing is working.

Thanks for the help.
Charlie Magee

Comment: You'll probably need to do something like this: `$("#popoverframe").contents().find("#popoverframe").contents().find("#player #video-player-flash").stop()`

Comment: Also `$('#player > #video-player-flash');` would be incorrect if `#video-player-flash` is a child of `#playercontainer`. it would be `$('#player #video-player-flash');`

Comment: Nope. Doesn't change anything. Various combinations based on this not working either.

Answer (score -1):

You have a jQuery object set to myPlayer instead of the
DOM node.

```
var myPlayer = $('#player > #video-player-flash')[0];
myPlayer.stopVideo();
```

See this post: [How can I stop a video with Javascript in Youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094397/how-can-i-stop-a-video-with-javascript-in-youtube)

Comment: @ryan--that changed the error message but didn't fix the problem. New error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'stopVideo' of undefined

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a minimal implementation on jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem. You also might want to use console.log to see if the element you are selecting is the correct embed element or not.

Comment: @ryan--this has a bunch of php includes and database searching going on. Simplifying it to make a fiddle won't help. Console.log just comes up empty as soon as I pass the first iframe. That's one of the reasons  I turned to stackoverflow.